# nc or socat: How to read data from remote:/dev/ttyACM0?

Tags: linux, ssh, netcat

I have a device running at a remote computer on /dev/ttyACM0
Now I want to read that data on my computer.  I can connect to it over ssh.
Unfortunately I am a `nc`/`socat` rookie and no howto covered this.

Semantically like this:

```
  cat remote:/dev/ttyACM0
```

The remote system has a limited linux on it, and I can't install packages.
(`socat` is not available there, `nc` is)

Super cool would be to have some forwarded device:

```
local:/dev/ttySOCK0   pointing to   remote:/dev/ttyACM0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ser2net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ser2net/) and [cyclades-serial-client](http://www.coker.com.au/cyclades/) look promising.

Answer (score 1):

I found the Solution to part One:

```
on remote: cat /dev/ttyACM0 | nc -l -p 44144

on local: nc remote 44144
```

2nd part still open:
Would there be a way to make a character device out of souch a "pipe"?

Comment: You could probably use socat to relay the data into a named pipe - which might be enough.